# Left Join on different source if nulll

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to do a left join on Table A. I have the main column of Table B I wish to join on, however there is a possibility of null values. How can I write my query where if the first left join column returns a null value, it will look for matches in the secondary column?

```
select a.Node, b.Amps
from A
left join on 
a.node = b.Node
--IF NULL left join on a.node = b.name
--if still no match, then return null
```

Comment: You can use `COALESCE()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OR` when the first condition is not true and your secondary join condition:

```sql
select a.Node,
       b.Amps
from   A
       left join B
       on    a.node = b.Node
          OR (   (a.node <> b.node OR a.node IS NULL OR b.node IS NULL)
             AND a.node = b.name
             )
```

or, if you don't want `name` matches when the `node` matches then you can use a `LATERAL` join and use `FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES` and an `ORDER BY` clause to set the priority:

```sql
select a.Node,
       b.Amps
from   A
       LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT *
         FROM   B
         WHERE  a.node = b.Node
         OR     a.node = b.name
         ORDER BY
                CASE WHEN a.node = b.node THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
         FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES
       )
       ON 1 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one way:

```
select a.Node, b.Amps
from A a
left join B b
   on a.node IN (b.Node, b.name)
```

Comment: Thanks! Would it prioritize b.node first? Thats what im hoping to achieve

Comment: @cpljp It will match on both with equal priority.

Comment: @MT0 is there a way to have it prioritize b.node first?